# Adjacency matrix from Dataframe

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix

I have the following dataframe.

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Italy, Spain |
| 2 | Spain, South Africa |
| 3 | France, Germany |
| 4 | Germany, Spain |

and would like to set ID as index and get the following matrix:

| ID | France | Germany | Italy | Spain | South Africa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At `ID == 3`, Germany should have `1`. Also, I assume you want the columns in alphabetical order, so `Spain` and `South Africa` should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies) for this, with `', '` as the `separator`.

```
res = df.set_index('ID').Country.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')

print(res)

    France  Germany  Italy  South Africa  Spain
ID                                             
1        0        0      1             0      1
2        0        0      0             1      1
3        1        1      0             0      0
4        0        1      0             0      1
```